# QGIS versions yielding different results on $area calculations?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, area

When grading an exam, I discovered that QGIS 3.2 and 3.4 produce different values on computing `$area` over polygons.

I experimented using `$area` and `area($geometry)` to check the differences between planar and ellipsoid computations. It seems that QGIS 2.18 computes planar areas as default for `$area`, whereas QGIS 3.4 gives ellipsoidal areas for `$area` (as explained at the help section of the function).

In QGIS 3.2, `$area` produces different values (quite higher) than those for `$area` in QGIS 3.4, whereas `area($geometry)` produces the same values in the two versions.

As context, my data is projected on EPSG:32717 (WGS84 UTM z17 S).

Any insights on what's going on? Is this a bug? I'd like to explain the students these caveats and to be aware when computing area-derived variables.

[image: area values for different QGIS versions]

Comment: Some of the ellipsoidal area calculations were refined in 3.4. the values should be more accurate on 3.4 vs 3.2

Comment: @ndawson...will this be addressed in the 3.4 changelog? It's kind of a critical differnce when you're assessing large hectare lots!

Comment: @ndawson please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as answered

Answer (score 3):

As @ndawson noted in the comments above:

> Some of the ellipsoidal area calculations were refined in 3.4. the values should be more accurate on 3.4 vs 3.2

You can see the source code changes at: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/297dbe0786d30b7b05462c8dac49b51f13175a19 and 
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/d85039363a552b901da81467f45925f183bd50a6